# Iphone : unrecognized selector sent to instance & viewDidLoad isn't running

Tags: iphone, selector

I'm developing an application.
I used a TabBar and every tab have its Class (FirstViewController, SecondViewController, ... )
There is one AppDelegate too.

When I launch the program, the first Class is running.
When i select the second tab, the `Secondview`.xib 's running but the "`viewDidLoad`" isn't working.
When I select the third Tab, that's the same.

I've put some buttons on the third tab, and when I push it, I have a

```
 > -[UIViewController testAuthentication:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f16920
    2011-04-08 13:46:42.511 e-mars[19501:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController testAuthentication:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f16920'
```

Here's the code of my classes

**SecondViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
}
@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@implementation SecondViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"viewDidLoad de SecondViewController");

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://iosdevelopertips.com/images/logo-iphone-dev-tips.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]; 

[self.view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

**ThirdViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UITextField *login;
IBOutlet UITextField *motdepasse;
NSMutableData *responseData;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *login;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *motdepasse;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableData *responseData;
- (IBAction) testAuthentication: (id)sender;
- (IBAction) saveAuthentication: (id)sender;
@end
```

**ThirdViewController.m**

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@implementation ThirdViewController

@synthesize login;
@synthesize motdepasse;
@synthesize responseData;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    //if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Initialization code
    //}
    return self;
}

-(IBAction) testAuthentication: (id)sender {
    //NSLog(@"testAuthentication");
}


- (IBAction) saveAuthentication: (id)sender {
    NSLog(@"saveAuthentication");
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [login dealloc];
    [motdepasse dealloc];
    [responseData dealloc];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: We need to see the code in which you call "testauthentication" to have a chance to see where the problem is.

Comment: NSLog(@"testAuthentication"); is the only code in the method for the moment (and doesn't run ... indeed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third ViewController doesn't actually create an instance, so no instance methods can be called upon it. Fix your initWithFrame: method. Remember: instance methods start with the '-' sign, class methods start with the '+' sign.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self)) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle 
{
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (id)init 
{
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```

After you fixed this, at least the viewDidLoad method in the third ViewController should work.

With regards to the second ViewController, could you please show the code you use to instantiate the ViewController?

**Edit:** I've made some changed to make sure *initWithFrame:* is always called upon initialization, just in case you create the instance using another method (*initWithNibName:bundle:* or *init*), now *initWithFrame:* has become the *designated initializer*.

Comment: I've changed the initializer method, please try with the -initWithNibName:bundle: method, this method is guaranteed to be on any UIViewController subclass.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm puzzled why you've got these issues. I guess you've used the graphical interface designer to create the viewcontrollers? I usually create GUIs for the iPhone in code, since it's more flexible. I also guess you're new to programming in ObjC / for the iPhone? If this is true, I suggest you start over, but build the whole view hierarchy in code, without using any of the graphical design tools. This is a more flexible approach anyway (allows for find / replace actions, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Set class in Viewcontroller.

and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Object`  On which your are calling `testAuthentication`

May be you are calling `testAuthentication` on secondViewController's object , Just check and let us know

Comment: [link](http://www.imagup.com/data/1116934918.html) the interface builder seems to be set correctly

Comment: I don't understand where the object is created :-/

Comment: Where can I instantiate the classes (by clicking a tab) ?

Answer (score 0):

First time alone the `viewController` will come from `viewDidLoad` after that it does not call `viewDidLoad` instead it calls `viewWillAppear`. so you can code whatever you want in `viewWillAppear`.